# Is it possible to change a static variable of a jQuery plugin on window.onresize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

So I have this plugin (well, part of it anyways). On window resize, I'd like to change the value of the width variable. Is this possible?

Here's the code:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.slides = function( option ) {
        // override defaults with specified option
        option = $.extend( {}, $.fn.slides.option, option );

        return this.each(function(){
            // wrap slides in control container, make sure slides are block level
            $('.' + option.container, $(this)).children().wrapAll('<div class="slides_control"/>');

            var elem = $(this),
                control = $('.slides_control',elem),
                total = control.children().size(),
                width = control.children().outerWidth(),
                height = control.children().outerHeight(),
                start = option.start - 1,
                effect = option.effect.indexOf(',') < 0 ? option.effect : option.effect.replace(' ', '').split(',')[0],
                paginationEffect = option.effect.indexOf(',') < 0 ? effect : option.effect.replace(' ', '').split(',')[1],
                next = 0, prev = 0, number = 0, current = 0, loaded, active, clicked, position, direction, imageParent, pauseTimeout, playInterval;
            }
        )};

    }
);
```

I tried using

```
$.slides.width = 1000;
```

But to no avail. Please help!

Here's the rest of the code (it's slidesjs):

```
(function($){
    $.fn.slides = function( option ) {
        // override defaults with specified option
        option = $.extend( {}, $.fn.slides.option, option );

        return this.each(function(){
            // wrap slides in control container, make sure slides are block level
            $('.' + option.container, $(this)).children().wrapAll('<div class="slides_control"/>');

            var elem = $(this),
                control = $('.slides_control',elem),
                total = control.children().size(),
                width = control.children().outerWidth(),
                height = control.children().outerHeight(),
                start = option.start - 1,
                effect = option.effect.indexOf(',') < 0 ? option.effect : option.effect.replace(' ', '').split(',')[0],
                paginationEffect = option.effect.indexOf(',') < 0 ? effect : option.effect.replace(' ', '').split(',')[1],
                next = 0, prev = 0, number = 0, current = 0, loaded, active, clicked, position, direction, imageParent, pauseTimeout, playInterval;

            // is there only one slide?
            if (total < 2) {
                // Fade in .slides_container
                $('.' + option.container, $(this)).fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing, function(){
                    // let the script know everything is loaded
                    loaded = true;
                    // call the loaded funciton
                    option.slidesLoaded();
                });
                // Hide the next/previous buttons
                $('.' + option.next + ', .' + option.prev).fadeOut(0);
                return false;
            }

            // animate slides
            function animate(direction, effect, clicked) {
                if (!active && loaded) {
                    active = true;
                    // start of animation
                    option.animationStart(current + 1);
                    switch(direction) {
                        case 'next':
                            // change current slide to previous
                            prev = current;
                            // get next from current + 1
                            next = current + 1;
                            // if last slide, set next to first slide
                            next = total === next ? 0 : next;
                            // set position of next slide to right of previous
                            position = width*2;
                            // distance to slide based on width of slides
                            direction = -width*2;
                            // store new current slide
                            current = next;
                            log(width);
                        break;
                        case 'prev':
                            // change current slide to previous
                            prev = current;
                            // get next from current - 1
                            next = current - 1;
                            // if first slide, set next to last slide
                            next = next === -1 ? total-1 : next;                                
                            // set position of next slide to left of previous
                            position = 0;                               
                            // distance to slide based on width of slides
                            direction = 0;      
                            // store new current slide
                            current = next;
                        break;
                        case 'pagination':
                            // get next from pagination item clicked, convert to number
                            next = parseInt(clicked,10);
                            // get previous from pagination item with class of current
                            prev = $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li.'+ option.currentClass +' a', elem).attr('href').match('[^#/]+$');
                            // if next is greater then previous set position of next slide to right of previous
                            if (next > prev) {
                                position = width*2;
                                direction = -width*2;
                            } else {
                            // if next is less then previous set position of next slide to left of previous
                                position = 0;
                                direction = 0;
                            }
                            // store new current slide
                            current = next;
                        break;
                    }

                    // fade animation
                    if (effect === 'fade') {
                        // fade animation with crossfade
                        if (option.crossfade) {
                            // put hidden next above current
                            control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).css({
                                zIndex: 10
                            // fade in next
                            }).fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing, function(){
                                if (option.autoHeight) {
                                    // animate container to height of next
                                    control.animate({
                                        height: control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).outerHeight()
                                    }, option.autoHeightSpeed, function(){
                                        // hide previous
                                        control.children(':eq('+ prev +')', elem).css({
                                            display: 'none',
                                            zIndex: 0
                                        });                             
                                        // reset z index
                                        control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).css({
                                            zIndex: 0
                                        });                                 
                                        // end of animation
                                        option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                        active = false;
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    // hide previous
                                    control.children(':eq('+ prev +')', elem).css({
                                        display: 'none',
                                        zIndex: 0
                                    });                                 
                                    // reset zindex
                                    control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).css({
                                        zIndex: 0
                                    });                                 
                                    // end of animation
                                    option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                    active = false;
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            // fade animation with no crossfade
                            control.children(':eq('+ prev +')', elem).fadeOut(option.fadeSpeed,  option.fadeEasing, function(){
                                // animate to new height
                                if (option.autoHeight) {
                                    control.animate({
                                        // animate container to height of next
                                        height: control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).outerHeight()
                                    }, option.autoHeightSpeed,
                                    // fade in next slide
                                    function(){
                                        control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing);
                                    });
                                } else {
                                // if fixed height
                                    control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing, function(){
                                        // fix font rendering in ie, lame
                                        if($.browser.msie) {
                                            $(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
                                        }
                                    });
                                }                                   
                                // end of animation
                                option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                active = false;
                            });
                        }
                    // slide animation
                    } else {
                        // move next slide to right of previous
                        control.children(':eq('+ next +')').css({
                            left: position,
                            display: 'block'
                        });
                        // animate to new height
                        if (option.autoHeight) {
                            control.animate({
                                left: direction,
                                height: control.children(':eq('+ next +')').outerHeight()
                            },option.slideSpeed, option.slideEasing, function(){
                                control.css({
                                    left: -width
                                });
                                control.children(':eq('+ next +')').css({
                                    left: width,
                                    zIndex: 5
                                });
                                // reset previous slide
                                control.children(':eq('+ prev +')').css({
                                    left: width,
                                    display: 'none',
                                    zIndex: 0
                                });
                                // end of animation
                                option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                active = false;
                            });
                            // if fixed height
                            } else {
                                // animate control
                                control.animate({
                                    left: direction
                                },option.slideSpeed, option.slideEasing, function(){
                                    // after animation reset control position
                                    control.css({
                                        left: -width
                                    });
                                    // reset and show next
                                    control.children(':eq('+ next +')').css({
                                        left: width,
                                        zIndex: 5
                                    });
                                    // reset previous slide
                                    control.children(':eq('+ prev +')').css({
                                        left: width,
                                        display: 'none',
                                        zIndex: 0
                                    });
                                    // end of animation
                                    option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                    active = false;
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    // set current state for pagination
                    if (option.pagination) {
                        // remove current class from all
                        $('.'+ option.paginationClass +' li.' + option.currentClass, elem).removeClass(option.currentClass);
                        // add current class to next
                        $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li:eq('+ next +')', elem).addClass(option.currentClass);
                    }
                }
            } // end animate function

            function stop() {
                // clear interval from stored id
                clearInterval(elem.data('interval'));
            }

            function pause() {
                if (option.pause) {
                    // clear timeout and interval
                    clearTimeout(elem.data('pause'));
                    clearInterval(elem.data('interval'));
                    // pause slide show for option.pause amount
                    pauseTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        // clear pause timeout
                        clearTimeout(elem.data('pause'));
                        // start play interval after pause
                        playInterval = setInterval( function(){
                            animate("next", effect);
                        },option.play);
                        // store play interval
                        elem.data('interval',playInterval);
                    },option.pause);
                    // store pause interval
                    elem.data('pause',pauseTimeout);
                } else {
                    // if no pause, just stop
                    stop();
                }
            }

            // 2 or more slides required
            if (total < 2) {
                return;
            }

            // error corection for start slide
            if (start < 0) {
                start = 0;
            }

            if (start > total) {
                start = total - 1;
            }

            // change current based on start option number
            if (option.start) {
                current = start;
            }

            // randomizes slide order
            if (option.randomize) {
                control.randomize();
            }

            // make sure overflow is hidden, width is set
            $('.' + option.container, elem).css({
                overflow: 'hidden',
                // fix for ie
                position: 'relative'
            });

            // set css for slides
            control.children().css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0, 
                left: control.children().outerWidth(),
                zIndex: 0,
                display: 'none'
             });

            // set css for control div
            control.css({
                position: 'relative',
                // size of control 3 x slide width
                width: (width * 3),
                // set height to slide height
                height: height,
                // center control to slide
                left: -width
            });

            // show slides
            $('.' + option.container, elem).css({
                display: 'block'
            });

            // if autoHeight true, get and set height of first slide
            if (option.autoHeight) {
                control.children().css({
                    height: 'auto'
                });
                control.animate({
                    height: control.children(':eq('+ start +')').outerHeight()
                },option.autoHeightSpeed);
            }

            // checks if image is loaded
            if (option.preload && control.find('img:eq(' + start + ')').length) {
                // adds preload image
                $('.' + option.container, elem).css({
                    background: 'url(' + option.preloadImage + ') no-repeat 50% 50%'
                });

                // gets image src, with cache buster
                var img = control.find('img:eq(' + start + ')').attr('src') + '?' + (new Date()).getTime();

                // check if the image has a parent
                if ($('img', elem).parent().attr('class') != 'slides_control') {
                    // If image has parent, get tag name
                    imageParent = control.children(':eq(0)')[0].tagName.toLowerCase();
                } else {
                    // Image doesn't have parent, use image tag name
                    imageParent = control.find('img:eq(' + start + ')');
                }

                // checks if image is loaded
                control.find('img:eq(' + start + ')').attr('src', img).load(function() {
                    // once image is fully loaded, fade in
                    control.find(imageParent + ':eq(' + start + ')').fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing, function(){
                        $(this).css({
                            zIndex: 5
                        });
                        // removes preload image
                        $('.' + option.container, elem).css({
                            background: ''
                        });
                        // let the script know everything is loaded
                        loaded = true;
                        // call the loaded funciton
                        option.slidesLoaded();
                    });
                });
            } else {
                // if no preloader fade in start slide
                control.children(':eq(' + start + ')').fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing, function(){
                    // let the script know everything is loaded
                    loaded = true;
                    // call the loaded funciton
                    option.slidesLoaded();
                });
            }

            // click slide for next
            if (option.bigTarget) {
                // set cursor to pointer
                control.children().css({
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                });
                // click handler
                control.children().click(function(){
                    // animate to next on slide click
                    animate('next', effect);
                    return false;
                });                                 
            }

            // pause on mouseover
            if (option.hoverPause && option.play) {
                control.bind('mouseover',function(){
                    // on mouse over stop
                    stop();
                });
                control.bind('mouseleave',function(){
                    // on mouse leave start pause timeout
                    pause();
                });
            }

            // generate next/prev buttons
            if (option.generateNextPrev) {
                $('.' + option.container, elem).after('<div class="control"><a href="#" class="'+ option.prev +'">&lt;</a>');
                $('.' + option.prev, elem).after('<div class="slideCount">' + (current+1) + '</div> /&nbsp;&nbsp;' + total +'<a href="#" class="'+ option.next +'">&gt;</a></div>');
            }

            // next button
            $('.' + option.next ,elem).click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if (option.play) {
                    pause();
                }
                animate('next', effect);
                $('.slideCount').html(current+1);
            });

            // previous button
            $('.' + option.prev, elem).click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if (option.play) {
                     pause();
                }
                animate('prev', effect);
                $('.slideCount').html(current+1);
            });

            // generate pagination
            if (option.generatePagination) {
                // create unordered list
                if (option.prependPagination) {
                    elem.prepend('<ul class='+ option.paginationClass +'></ul>');
                } else {
                    elem.append('<ul class='+ option.paginationClass +'></ul>');
                }
                // for each slide create a list item and link
                control.children().each(function(){
                    $('.' + option.paginationClass, elem).append('<li><a href="#'+ number +'">'+ (number+1) +'</a></li>');
                    number++;
                });
            } else {
                // if pagination exists, add href w/ value of item number to links
                $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li a', elem).each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('href', '#' + number);
                    number++;
                });
            }

            // add current class to start slide pagination
            $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li:eq('+ start +')', elem).addClass(option.currentClass);

            // click handling 
            $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li a', elem ).click(function(){
                // pause slideshow
                if (option.play) {
                     pause();
                }
                // get clicked, pass to animate function                    
                clicked = $(this).attr('href').match('[^#/]+$');
                // if current slide equals clicked, don't do anything
                if (current != clicked) {
                    animate('pagination', paginationEffect, clicked);
                }
                return false;
            });

            // click handling 
            $('a.link', elem).click(function(){
                // pause slideshow
                if (option.play) {
                     pause();
                }
                // get clicked, pass to animate function                    
                clicked = $(this).attr('href').match('[^#/]+$') - 1;
                // if current slide equals clicked, don't do anything
                if (current != clicked) {
                    animate('pagination', paginationEffect, clicked);
                }
                return false;
            });

            if (option.play) {
                // set interval
                playInterval = setInterval(function() {
                    animate('next', effect);
                }, option.play);
                // store interval id
                elem.data('interval',playInterval);
            }
        });
    };

    // default options
    $.fn.slides.option = {
        preload: false, // boolean, Set true to preload images in an image based slideshow
        preloadImage: '/img/loading.gif', // string, Name and location of loading image for preloader. Default is "/img/loading.gif"
        container: 'slides_container', // string, Class name for slides container. Default is "slides_container"
        generateNextPrev: false, // boolean, Auto generate next/prev buttons
        next: 'next', // string, Class name for next button
        prev: 'prev', // string, Class name for previous button
        pagination: true, // boolean, If you're not using pagination you can set to false, but don't have to
        generatePagination: true, // boolean, Auto generate pagination
        prependPagination: false, // boolean, prepend pagination
        paginationClass: 'pagination', // string, Class name for pagination
        currentClass: 'current', // string, Class name for current class
        fadeSpeed: 350, // number, Set the speed of the fading animation in milliseconds
        fadeEasing: '', // string, must load jQuery's easing plugin before http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
        slideSpeed: 350, // number, Set the speed of the sliding animation in milliseconds
        slideEasing: '', // string, must load jQuery's easing plugin before http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
        start: 1, // number, Set the speed of the sliding animation in milliseconds
        effect: 'slide', // string, '[next/prev], [pagination]', e.g. 'slide, fade' or simply 'fade' for both
        crossfade: false, // boolean, Crossfade images in a image based slideshow
        randomize: false, // boolean, Set to true to randomize slides
        play: 0, // number, Autoplay slideshow, a positive number will set to true and be the time between slide animation in milliseconds
        pause: 0, // number, Pause slideshow on click of next/prev or pagination. A positive number will set to true and be the time of pause in milliseconds
        hoverPause: false, // boolean, Set to true and hovering over slideshow will pause it
        autoHeight: false, // boolean, Set to true to auto adjust height
        autoHeightSpeed: 350, // number, Set auto height animation time in milliseconds
        bigTarget: false, // boolean, Set to true and the whole slide will link to next slide on click
        animationStart: function(){}, // Function called at the start of animation
        animationComplete: function(){}, // Function called at the completion of animation
        slidesLoaded: function() {} // Function is called when slides is fully loaded
    };

    // Randomize slide order on load
    $.fn.randomize = function(callback) {
        function randomizeOrder() { return(Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); }
            return($(this).each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $children = $this.children();
            var childCount = $children.length;
            if (childCount > 1) {
                $children.hide();
                var indices = [];
                for (i=0;i<childCount;i++) { indices[indices.length] = i; }
                indices = indices.sort(randomizeOrder);
                $.each(indices,function(j,k) { 
                    var $child = $children.eq(k);
                    var $clone = $child.clone(true);
                    $clone.show().appendTo($this);
                    if (callback !== undefined) {
                        callback($child, $clone);
                    }
                $child.remove();
            });
            }
        }));
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Do you have source of the code where you got this from?

Comment: Nope, i get an error that says, cannot get property width of undefined

Comment: There is no property `width` in `option` object.

Comment: There is a property `preload` and it's property is `false` by default but if you want to change it's value to `true` then you can write `$.fn.slides.option.preload=true;`

Comment: @Sheikh Heera Actually, the error message says the `option` object does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the width you have to define the resize event somewhere within the scope of that variable.
maybe right before this line:

```
// is there only one slide?
if (total < 2) {
```

attach an event handler to the window

```
$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
   // width is available here
   width = control.children().outerWidth() // recalculates width
});
```